# Question about duct work replacing a bathroom fan

Tags: plumbing, hvac, ducts, exhaust-fan

I am replacing a bathroom exhaust fan with a humidity sensing model that automatically turns on when a specified humidity level is reached. The original duct is 3" wide. I had to get a 4" to 3" reducer.

I read in the instruction manual I should cover the ducting with insulation. The majority of this duct will be buried under blown-in insulation.

This was originally held up with duct support webbing seen in the pictures. It created some sharp bends in the line. I removed all the support webbing and tried to make the exhaust line as straight as possible.

Does this look ok to you guys so far?

**EDIT:** I understand the restriction of moving from 4" to 3". The problem is I dont have the expertise to change the roof vent to a 4". That is why I tried to make the duct as straight as possible. I believe the fan should be able to handle this though. This is a Panasonic Whisperquiet fan. From the instruction manual:

> Optimum Ventilation Performance:
> Duct length, elbows and other factors increase static pressure which can hinder the performance of most ventilation fans. This fan utilizes Smart Flow microchip technology that monitors the static pressure in the system and speeds up or slows down the RPM of the fan depending upon the amount of resistance within the ducts. This feature allows the fan to perform as rated and avoid potential installation issues.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It normally not a good idea to reduce duct size. I would try to find something that is smooth inside and run the larger size until it leaves the building then reduce it. You are adding a lot of restriction this way. Straightening the line out is good but do not forget to take your drill with you:-)

Comment: Thanks Gil, that is something I forgot to mention in my OP. I understand the restriction, that is why I tried to make it as straight as possible. My plan is to eventually replace the vent on the roof to a 4" vent.

Comment: Also, the fan says it can modulate based on restriction. From the manual:<<Optimum Ventilation Performance:>>
---- Duct length, elbows and other factors increase static pressure which can hinder the performance of most ventilation fans. This fan utilizes Smart Flow microchip technology that monitors the static pressure in the system and speeds up or slows down the RPM of the fan depending upon the amount of resistance within the ducts. This feature allows the fan to perform as rated and avoid potential installation issues.